# How to stop/crash/fail a pod manually in Kubernetes/Openshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openshift, kubectl

I'm running `rook-ceph-cluster` on top of `AWS` with `3 masters - 3 worker node` configuration.
I have created my cluster using [this](https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.0/ceph-examples.html).

Each `worker node` is `100 GiB` each.

After setting everything up. I have my pods running (6 pods to be exact,3 for master and 3 for nodes).

**How can I crash/fail/stop those pods manually (to test some functionality)?.**

Is there is any way **I can add more load manually to those pods so that it can crash?**.

Or **can I somehow make them `Out Of Memory`?.**

Or **can I simulate intermittent network failures and disconnection of nodes from the network?**

Or **any other ways like writing some script that might prevent a pod to be created?**

Comment: To simulate crashing pods, run `oc delete pod pod-name`.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete pods manually as mentioned by Graham, but the rest are trickier. For simulating an OOM, you could `kubectl exec` into the pod and run something that will burn up RAM. Or you could set the limit down below what it actually uses. Simulating network issues would be up to your CNI plugin, but I'm not aware of any that allow failure injection. For preventing a pod from being created, you can set an affinity it that is not fulfilled by any node.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to force a restart is to kill the running process.

`kubectl exec your-pod-name -- kill 1`

Answer (score 0):

To force crashloopbackOff of an nginx pod I did :

```
 kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -n <namespace> -- bash -c "kill 1"
```